# Unity Vuforia AR camera goes black

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia

So I want to recognize 3D object when I try to do that in unity , AR CAMERA shows just black screen. Im totaly new at this interface, so dont be mad at me if this question is ridiculous .

[image]

Or maybe i should change profiles.xml file like this: (ADDED THESE LINES BY MYSELF)
[image]

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Unity Editor on Windows? Afaik, Vuforia only supports 32-bit architecture by now.

Comment: Yes, Im using 64Bit Unity, you think I should install 32bit?

Comment: If you want to see Vuforia webcam video on Unity Editor, it is the only way for now. But if you deploy on real device, it is not necessary. In fact, I am using Unity 64-bit, and play with Vuforia on real device just fine. Because I am developing mobile games, I do not care about Vuforia behavior on PC version, and I just fake the camera position for testing.

Comment: Do you use Vuforia version 4? you can see version 4.0.105 Vuforia supports 64bit Unity, in [release notes](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Release_Notes/Vuforia-40-SDK-Release-Notes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add direction light from gameobject->light->directional light option and add to root

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your solution does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains a solution (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the latest (current) 4.0.11 beta, and you import any of the Vuforia samples unity packages, the rendering settings should be automatically enforced and switched to OpenGL ES 2.0;

in any case, the OpenGL ES 2.0 (as of today) is the correct settings to use in Unity, so, if the rendering settings are not set to that,  then you'll need to manually set them to GL ES 2.0 in the Player Settings menu;

the "Metal" graphics API is not yet supported by Vuforia at this time.

Answer (score 2):

In Unity Player Settings : Other Settings find the Rendering part, uncheck the Auto Graphics API and select only OpenGLES2 and rebuild your unity project.

This solved my issue

Comment: This worked for me too. Do you know any technical reason why Automatic API doesn't work.